# Get All Value in Array except "x" value Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm new in IOS programming. I have a question, how  to get all value in array except x value. Let say i have array like below :

```
let array : [Any] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,200]
```

how to print all value except 1 and 2.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092712/how-to-remove-an-element-of-a-given-value-from-an-array-in-swift) , its using `filter` and i try it with playground but i still not have the right value. Any answer will helpfull for me. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Show your sample code with `filter` that does not work

Comment: Your array is not `[Any]`, it's `[Int]`. **Do not annotate types the compiler can infer**. In many cases like this one you make it worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why you have defined the array as `[Any]` so I just removed that and the array is:-

`let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,200]`

Next you can use `filter` as follows:-

`let filtered = array.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    return element != 1 && element != 2
}`

You can test this out in the playground, it will print all values except 1 & 2

You can also use some syntactical sugar for `filter` as follows:-

`array.filter({ return $0 != 1 && $0 != 2 })`

And since the closure is a trailing argument, you can also separate it from the arguments as follows:-

`array.filter { return $0 != 1 && $0 != 2 }`

Another way to do this would be

`let filterTheseOut = [1,2]`

`let anotherWay = array.filter { !filterTheseOut.contains($0) }`

So here you can basically add all the elements to be filtered out in a separate array

Comment: thanks, i have try if using loop `for` before and its work for me. but now i want to know if using filter. your answer is better than other

Comment: i have a question, what the meaning `$0` ?

Comment: if a closure takes argument(s) but you do not wish to name those arguments, you can refer to them as $0, $1 etc.

Comment: I would also appreciate if you could accept the answer

Comment: ohh i see. 5 minutes for checked. Thanks i understand now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
let array : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,200]

print(array.filter { $0 != 1 && $0 != 2 } )
```

or if you will have more than 1 or 2 values you can put them into array

```
let array : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,200]
let unwantedValues = [1,2]
print(array.filter { unwantedValues.contains($0) == false } )
```

Next time please paste your code, it will be easier to tell you what you're doing wrong, then giving you ready solution.

Comment: thanks, i think my question is very clear to understand. But next time i will. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

No need for filter use this:

```
for i in array {
 if i != 1 && i != 2 {
 print i
 }
}
```

// This will print all values except 1 and 2