# How do I remove a value from swift array of enums

Tags: swift3

Similar to this [How to remove an element of a given value from an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092712/how-to-remove-an-element-of-a-given-value-from-an-array-in-swift)

but for enums

how would I remove a value with a given enum (native swift enum that does
not allow comparison) from an array of those enums?

can't convert that enum to Int cause there are some parameterized cases

sample code (that does not compile):

```
    enum test
    {
        case foo
        case bar(baz: Locale)
    }

    var arr: [test] = [.foo, .bar(baz: Locale.current)]

    arr = arr.filter({ $0 != .foo })
```

Comment: show us code, maybe, about what you have tried and how...?

Comment: What do you mean by "native swift enum that does not allow comparison?" Can you give an example of that?

Comment: added sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums with associated values aren't implicitly marked Equatable. You have to request it. But that's all you have to do if the associated values are themselves Equatable (as of Swift 4.2 I believe).

Change:

```
enum Test
```

to:

```
enum Test: Equatable
```

(Note: enums are types and should always be capitalized)

Answer (score 3):

Well isn't that something. It's right in the error message.

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be synthesized for enums with associated values
```

Quick answer:

```
arr = arr.filter {
    switch $0 {
    case .foo: return true
    default: return false
    }
}
```

More compact answer:

```
arr = arr.filter { if case .foo = $0 { return true } else { return false } }
```

More maintainable answer:

If there are only a few values in `test`, move the logic into the enum.

```
extension test {

    var isFoo: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .foo: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }

    var isBar: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .bar: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }

}

arr = arr.filter { $0.isFoo }
```